# TFS msdeploy with publishprofile options does not work

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, msdeploy

I have installed TFS 2018 Community and was trying to publish a project to plesk domain using one of the publish profiles in the arguments of msdeploy task as shown in the picture below but it only build the project but did not publish it like I thought it would

[image: TFS Msdeploy]

Comment: no platform/configuration configured ? and the "Get sources"-task looks empty. Pls check theese configurations and try again.

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @lostmylogin What's your expected behavior?

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT It should work like visual studio's publish dialog

Comment: @lostmylogin Is that working when run the msdeploy command directly on local VS with the publishprofile? I mean run  `msbuild <path-to-project-file> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<Publish Profile> /p:Username=<USERNAME> /p:Password=<PASSWORD> .... arguments...` on your local VS.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT Yes

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT I am doing it using tfs on another machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally if you can run the msbuild command successfully with the arguments on local VS, then it should be also available in TFS.

So, please check below things to narrow down the issue:

- Just make sure you have the same components installed and configured
  on your build agent machine.
- Make sure you have the correct configuration for your build
  definition.

  - Based on your screenshot above, just try to set the correct `buildPlatform` and `buildConfiguration` (consistent with your project settings in VS).
  - Also verify that if you have checked in the `PublishProfiles`, and check the first  `Get sources` step, make sure the system can get the sources and  `PublishProfiles` during the build process.

This article for your reference : [TFS 2015: deploy website to IIS without installing extra add-ons to TFS](http://rredcat.blogspot.sg/2016/08/tfs-2015-deploy-website-to-iis-without.html)

---

**UPDATE:**

In order to use Publish Profiles on the build server, you have to have some of Visual Studio's prerequisites. Make sure you have installed the full version of Visual Studio on the build agent machine.

Besides, you can try with below arguments (Just change the `PackageLocation` value accordingly) :

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true  /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"
```

Referecne: [Working with Web Deploy and Release Management](https://blogs.like10.com/2016/09/08/working-with-web-deploy-and-release-management/) for the deployment.

Comment: This looks promising i will check it

Comment: @lostmylogin Have you resolved the issue by above suggestion? any update?

Comment: Nope did not work. It only build the solution nothing else

Comment: I will try the "Deploy IIS App" plugin now to see if that works

Comment: @lostmylogin In order to use Publish Profiles on the build server, you have to have some of Visual Studio's prerequisites. Make sure you have installed the full version of Visual Studio on the build agent machine. See the updated answer.